# Conways Game of Life in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, conways-game-of-life

I try to add a method that let a cell get alive if it's clicked by the left mouse button but I don't know how. I tried to add a MouseClickListener but I couldn't connect it to my code. I'm new to JavaFx so it's pretty hard to overview all the functions and how to use them. Every other function of my code works perfectly so far. I hope that anyone of you know how to implement this method. Here is my code:

```
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import javax.swing.*;


public class conway extends Application {

   private static final int width = 500;
   private static final int height = 500;
   private static final int cellsize = 10;
   private static Gson gson = new Gson();



   private static class Life{
       private final int reihe;
       private final int zeile;
       private Boolean[][] rules;
       private int[][] grid;
       private Random random=new Random();
       private final GraphicsContext graphics;

       public Life(int reihe, int zeile, GraphicsContext graphics){
           this.reihe =reihe;
           this.zeile =zeile;
           this.graphics=graphics;
           grid=new int[reihe][zeile];
           this.rules = new Boolean[][]{{false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                   {false, false, true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false}};
       }

       public void init(){
           for(int i = 0; i< reihe; i++){
               for(int j = 0; j< zeile; j++){
                   grid[i][j]=random.nextInt(2);
               }
           }
           draw();
       }

       private void draw(){
           graphics.setFill(Color.LAVENDER);
           graphics.fillRect(0,0,width,height);

           for(int i=0; i<grid.length;i++){
               for(int j=0; j<grid[i].length; j++){
                   if(grid[i][j]==1){
                       graphics.setFill(Color.gray(0.5,0.5));
                       graphics.fillRect(i*cellsize, j*cellsize,cellsize,cellsize);
                       graphics.setFill(Color.PURPLE);
                       graphics.fillRect((i*cellsize)+1, (j*cellsize)+1, cellsize-2, cellsize-2);

                   }
                   else{
                       graphics.setFill(Color.gray(0.5,0.5));
                       graphics.fillRect(i*cellsize,j*cellsize,cellsize, cellsize);
                       graphics.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                       graphics.fillRect((i*cellsize)+1,(j*cellsize)+1,cellsize-2,cellsize-2);

                   }
               }
           }
       }

       private int countNeighbors(int i, int j){
           int sum=0;
           int iStart=i==0?0:-1;
           int iEnd=i==grid.length - 1 ? 0:1;
           int jStart=j==0?0:-1;
           int jEnd=j==grid[0].length - 1 ? 0:1;

           for (int k=iStart; k<=iEnd;k++){
               for(int l=jStart;l<=jEnd;l++){
                   sum+=grid[i+k][l+j];
               }
           }
           sum-=grid[i][j];

           return sum;
       }

       public void tick(){
           int[][] next=new int[reihe][zeile];
           for(int i = 0; i< reihe; i++){
               for(int j = 0; j< zeile; j++){
                   int nachbar= countNeighbors(i,j);

                   if(rules[grid[i][j]][nachbar] == true){
                       next[i][j] = 1;
                   }
               }
           }
           grid=next;
           draw();
       }

       public void safe() throws IOException {
           JsonArray to_safe = new JsonArray();
           Path pfad = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Frodo\\IdeaProjects\\gameoflife\\only_safe_file_for_now.json");
           if(Files.exists(pfad) == false) {
               Files.createFile(pfad);
           }
           for(int i = 0; i<grid.length; i++){
               JsonArray helper = new JsonArray();
               for (int j = 0; j<grid[0].length; j++){
                   helper.add(grid[i][j]);
               }
               to_safe.add(helper);
           }
           Files.writeString(pfad, gson.toJson(to_safe));
       }

       public void load() throws IOException{
           int saved_grid[][];
           Path pfad = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Frodo\\IdeaProjects\\gameoflife\\only_safe_file_for_now.json");
           if(Files.exists(pfad) == false) {
               return;
           }
           else {
               String array_string = Files.readString(pfad);
               saved_grid = gson.fromJson(array_string, new TypeToken<int[][]>(){}.getType());
               if (saved_grid.length == 0) {
                   return;
               }
           }
           grid = saved_grid;
           draw();
       }


   }



   public static void main(String[] args) {

       launch();
   }


   public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
       VBox root = new VBox(10);
       Scene scene = new Scene(root, width, height + 100);
       final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(width, height);

       final boolean[] leftclick = new boolean[1];

       leftclick[0] =false;
       scene.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
           if(e.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)){
               if(leftclick[0]){
                   leftclick[0] =false;

               }
               else leftclick[0] =true;
           }
       });





       Button reset = new Button("Reset");
       Button step = new Button("Step");
       Button run = new Button("Run");
       Button stop = new Button("Stop");
       Button safe_state = new Button("Safe");
       Button load_button = new Button("Load");
       Button terminate = new Button("Terminate");



       root.getChildren().addAll(canvas, new HBox(10, reset, step, run, stop, safe_state, load_button, terminate));
       primaryStage.setScene(scene);
       primaryStage.show();

       int rows = (int) Math.floor(height / cellsize);
       int cols = (int) Math.floor(width / cellsize);

       GraphicsContext graphics = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
       Life life = new Life(rows, cols, graphics);
       life.init();

       AnimationTimer Animation = new AnimationTimer() {
           private long lastUpdate=0;
           @Override
           public void handle(long now) {

               if ((now - lastUpdate) >= TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(100)) {
                   life.tick();
                   lastUpdate = now;
               }
           }
       };

       reset.setOnAction(l -> life.init());
       run.setOnAction(l -> Animation.start());
       step.setOnAction(l -> life.tick());
       stop.setOnAction(l -> Animation.stop());
       safe_state.setOnAction(l-> {
           try {
               life.safe();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       });
       load_button.setOnAction(l -> {
           try {
               life.load();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       });
       terminate.setOnAction(l -> {
           Stage stage = (Stage) terminate.getScene().getWindow();
           stage.close();
       });
   }


}
```

Comment: This does not use `Canvas` but you can get some ideas from https://github.com/sedj601/ConwaysGameOfLife.

Comment: I am guessing `import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;` is leading to problems. I am also guessing `import javax.swing.*;` might be leading to problems. Try to use `JavaFX` imports only.

Answer (score 1):

Something in this direction should do the trick:

```
           canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, 
            new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent t) { 
                    // is left click
                    if (t == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                        grid[rows][cols] = 1;
                        draw();
                    }  
                }
            });
```

Comment: It looks fine, but I cannot access canvas if I use the eventhandler in class life. If I try to use it in start, I cannot use grid

Comment: @bfg tried with life.grid in start? or since its private create a getter. Or even better a setter, make a copy, edit the copy set the grid to the copy

Comment: Yeah, I tried but there is still a problem

Comment: @bfg in that case I'd start by refactoring(mix of English and German, not very clear method names etc.) and removing code from the question that isn't needed for the question (tick, safe, load, Animation etc.) maybe it'll become clearer then.

Comment: I added t.getButton() but now I got three errors. First one is that MouseEvent is not within bounds of type-variable, the non-static draw() cannot be referenced and addEventHandler cannot be applied to given types. Do you have any idea how to solve these problemes?